# What are the little "legs" on the bottom of a laptop called?

Tags: word-request

What is the proper name for the four legs (pads?) on the bottom of a laptop? I am thinking of those that are glued to the laptop and make the airflow circulation better under it.

Comment: I think enough native speakers wouldn't know the right term for these that the question would do just as well or perhaps better over on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @hippietrail I think ELU has more of a negative attitude

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For most equipment they are called *[feet](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/feet#Noun)*, but in the laptop context, add-on feet may be called *bumpers* or *stands*  ([1](http://jasontomczak.com/2009/10/good-inexpensive-laptop-feet/), [2](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/a695/)) as well. Phrases “self-stick rubber pads”  or “stick-on rubber pads” also may be used for particular kinds of feet.

Comment: "Rubber baby tablet bumpers." [:^)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-twister#Types_of_tongue-twisters)

Comment: "Risers" is general, but viable I think.

Answer (score 3):

They are called rectangular or circular rubber feet.

Comment: "rubber feet" does it for me (assuming they are made of rubber)